# jquery date time picker

Tags: jquery

could any body tell how to use Jquery calendar date time picker.

Comment: Go to demo page of your datepicker? Really, we won't give you better explanation than plugin authors.

Comment: The [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) are a pretty good starting point. Are you having a specific problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the following:

1. Download the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/download), which requires the UI core.
2. Add the script reference to your page, and CSS for the theme
3. Add the code to bind a datepicker to a textbox, as follows:

You can read the documentation here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

See:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

There is also the documentation with those demos.

Answer (score 1):

For the default options, it's simply

```
$(function() {  // function to execute when DOM is ready
    $('#input').datepicker(); // run datepicker on jQuery object
});
```

where you have

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

in your markup. You'll need to reference the scripts in the following order

1. jQuery script
2. datepicker script
3. Your script binding the datepicker on DOM ready.

for a more advanced example, **[check out this demo](http://jsbin.com/evudo)**. add **/edit** to the URL if you'd like to see the code behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider a native [HTML5 datepicker](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html). User Modernizr to decide whether to use browser native or not.

Answer (score 0):

What about using HTML5 and falling back to jQuery UI, if HTML5 datepicker is not available?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date){
        // if no native support, use a datepicker script
        $(':input[type=datetime]').datepicker();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#dateTime" ).datetimepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

});
```